# How much space does volume shadowing take up?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2012, volume-shadow-copy, shadow-copy

So for example in a server environment I set up shadowing on volume N, how much space do I assign for it?

Would a 1mb word document take up 1mb shadowing space on the volume?

Comment: Why the audio tag? `Would a 1mb word document take up 1mb shadowing space on the volume?` based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy#Overview) I believe your assumption is correct.

Comment: Every time I try to tag something I don't have enough rep not sure what else to do.. Thanks for confirming that is a lot of disk space then

Comment: Please specify the version of windows you are talking about.

Comment: Windows 2012 server

Comment: Windows server 2012 tag added, removed the generic "windows" tag, due to 5 tag set limit.

Comment: Anyone know please?